# View order of derived class variables in Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, itemsource

I have the following situation in a Visual Studio 2010 (C#) Silverlight 4 project using the `DataGrid` (this is pseudocode for brevity sake):

```
public class BaseClass {
    public string str1;
    public string str2;
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    public string str3;
    public string str4;
}

public List<DerivedClass> SetItemSource(List<DerivedClass> list) {
    dataGrid.ItemSource = list;
}
```

When I run the code, the columns are in the order:

> str3 str4 str1 str2

I would like them to display as:

> str1 str2 str3 str4

Is there any way of doing this?  I am finding the Silverlight `DataGrid` to be very inflexible.

Answer (score 0):

When I have just a standard class & I want to change the ordering of the columns, I use annotations:

```
[Display(Order=2)]
public string str1 { get; set }

[Display(Order=1)]
public string str2 { get; set; }
```

I just tried this with derived classes:

```
 public class BaseClass
    {
        [Display(Order=1)]
        public string str1 { get; set; }
        [Display(Order=3)]
        public string str2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        [Display(Order=4)]
        public string str3 { get; set; }
        [Display(Order=2)]
        public string str4 { get; set; }
    }
```

My grid columns were: str1 str4 str2 str3 as expected.

[EDIT]
Needed to include a using declaration: 
`using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` to use [Display...]
I really enjoy working with both the gridview & the dataform. Most people hate hate hate the dataform. Its taken many frustrating hours to understand  how to make it fit/work within our LOB apps, but now it's incredibly powerful and blazing fast for UI dev.

Also - if you're not familiar with Data Annotations, they're absolutely rad. You can set attributes like [Required(true)], [Display(Name="String 3")], [StringLength(3,ErrorMessage="This field can not exceed 3 characters in length")], Range(0,10,ErrorMessage="Must be 0-10)")] etc etc. The validation errors auto bubble up to the UI. They've saved seriously crazy amounts of time in our dev process.
[/EDIT]